# Getting "Page Not Found" After Enabling the Devel Module Drupal 7

Tags: debugging

I'm trying to install the [Theme Developer](https://www.drupal.org/project/devel_themer) which requires the Devel module.

I've downloaded the Devel module via the **Install new Module** page in Drupal. When I enable the module however, I get redirected to a "Page Not Found" error.

Going to **Reports** > **Recent log messages** shows:

```
page not found  06/14/2017 - 10:23  modules/statistics/statistics.php
page not found  06/14/2017 - 10:23  modules/statistics/statistics.php   
php 06/14/2017 - 10:22  User warning: The following module has moved within...
php 06/14/2017 - 10:22  User warning: The following module has moved within...  
php 06/14/2017 - 10:22  User warning: The following module has moved within...
```

The three PHP messages complain that **devel_node_access**, **devel**, and **devel_generate** have all been moved.

Could this be some form of permission issue?

---

**Edit**:
I just tried again, but this time used a different theme. Devel was still not enabled, but I was redirected to a different page; `/q=admin/modules&filter=devel&enabled=1&disabled=1&required=1&unavailable=1`. Now I can't view any of my site. I rebooted my VM but my site is still unresponsive. Looks like enabling Devel has broken my site somehow.

---

**Edit 2**:
Destroyed and rebuilt my VM. This time I **did not** change the theme to my custom theme, and instead left the default theme enabled. I refreshed all caches, and attempted to enable Devel (I didn't have to re-download anything since the modules were still in my VM directory). This time it worked! Devel is now enabled. I'm not going to write an answer to this until I know exactly what changed and why it's now working fine.

---

**Edit 3**:
After enabling Devel, SimpleHTMLDom Api, and Theme Developer, I now see the following error on **any** of my pages.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the theme developer module has not been touched in years and it is unsupported. You should not expect it to work at all and it is certainly plausible that it will have detrimental effects on your site.

Unfortunately I suspect that you are out of luck unless you want to dig into the code yourself and attempt to get the module into a working state that does not blow up your site.

Comment: or disable and remove it using drush

Comment: Didn't realise it was last developed so long ago. Thanks for the heads up.