# Find Out Which Template To Edit/Create

Tags: views, theming, nodes

I've got a Drupal 7 site with a default theme (Nuboot_Radix). How do I find out which template files (`.tpl.php`) are being used on each page. For example, I have the following page:

[image]

How do I find out which file to change in order to change how the datasets are displayed here (in this case **Age by Economic activity 2011**, **2011 UK Borders**, **Ethnic group 2011**).

I understand that I need to make these changes in a subtheme, which I have already created. But I don't know what to call the `tpl.php` files, what the put in them, what variables I can use, etc. If I could find out where the html was being created for that section then I can figure out the rest myself.

I have been advised in [another drupal post](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/238458/getting-page-not-found-after-enabling-the-devel-module-drupal-7/238497#238497) to not use Theme Developer since it is no longer supported.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`tpl.php` files are called templates in the Drupal system. They render the HTML that you see on any given page, may it be a block/view/panel or anything.

[Theme Developer](https://www.drupal.org/project/devel_themer) is a popular module used to pinpoint the template file that's in play. I suggest you try it to better understand how template system works.
To understand more on customizing templates and naming conventions read through this guide on [working with template suggestions](https://www.drupal.org/node/223440).

**If its a view you want to modify**- Use views GUI to the maximum extent(changing the sort order, re-arranging fields etc.). Still not getting what you want ? Override view templates for maximum control.

(Helpful Articles on overriding view templates)

http://www.wdtutorials.com/drupal/views/how-to-create-custom-template-view-drupal-tutorial-article

https://www.interworks.com/blog/carmstrong/2013/02/27/quick-tutorial-overriding-drupal-views-using-templates

Comment: Your advice is appreciated, however I have already used Theme Developer but ran into problems, as documented in [this Drupal.Stackexchange.com post](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/238458/getting-page-not-found-after-enabling-the-devel-module-drupal-7/238497#238497). I was advised not to use it since it is no longer supported. I shall add this information into the main question.

Comment: One of the articles you linked to pointed me towards adding `$conf['theme_debug'] = TRUE;` into my `settings.php` which allows me to view which nodes are being used when viewing the page source in Chrome.

Comment: @mohnjatthews Glad you figured. For anyone who might need this in future- OP was referring to https://www.drupal.org/node/223440