# theme_debug doesn't work

Tags: 7, theming

I wrote into my settings.php file (into default.settings.php file too):

```
$conf['theme_debug'] = TRUE;
$settings['theme_debug'] = TRUE;
$settings['theme_auto_reload'] = TRUE;
```

(These files have 777 permission.)

I have the "Theme developer" module.

I cleared all cache.

But the suggestions doesn't appear.

What else should I do?

(I have Drupal 7.)

Comment: Is this what the documentation for that module says you should do?

Comment: This might sound funny but did you enable the module and its dependencies ? It has a few dependencies from what I recall.

Comment: Are you talking about Theme developer? I enabled it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

People have been facing issues with [Theme Developer](https://www.drupal.org/project/devel_themer) module. If you installed this module just to get template suggestions, you might want to uninstall it and use `theme_debug` (only for d7) variable instead.

Enable this variable by adding `$conf[theme_debug]` to your **settings.php** or `drush vset theme_debug 1`

Then Perform a element inspect (or) view page source to get template suggestions. You may find this [article](https://www.drupal.org/node/223440#theme-debug) on drupal and the answer in this post helpful- [self promoting my answer](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/238551/find-out-which-template-to-edit-create/238553#238553).

Comment: I disabled the Theme Developer. This solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

In some installations the [minifyhtml](https://www.drupal.org/project/minifyhtml) module is used. If this is the case, the option “Strip comments from the source HTML” under /admin/config/development/performance/minifyhtml must be deactivated.